# What's the deal with different size GPS antennas?

Tags: rf, antenna, gps

I have some GPS modules laying around and I noticed they're pretty different size to each other.
(here are two of them for example):
[image: Different size GPS modules]

So doesn't any antenna have to be a specific size for a given frequency?

Does bigger mean better quality (of signal reception) in this case?

Are they just for different bands of GPS signal?

If they can be made different size what's the reason to make bigger ones?

Comment: GPS antenna can be made very small, but there's a trade off between sensitivity, directionality and cost.

Comment: Those are the modules. Show the actual antenna on the module.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik metallic coating on the ceramic part is the actual antenna.

Comment: @user1850479 So does that mean that the bigger one is better?